# Unicode character by name

Tags: unicode, julia

It is possible in julia 0.6 obtain the unicode character by its name?

In python it is possible by doing

```
s = u'\N{SECTION SIGN}'
```

There is something alike?
I know I can do

```
s =  '\u00a3'
```

but I want to do it by name.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [StringLiterals.jl](https://github.com/JuliaString/StringLiterals.jl) lets you do this.

via `s = f"\N{SECTION SIGN}"`

StringLiterals.jl was just registered the other day.
You can install it via `Pkg.add("StringLiterals")`

#### Examples

```
julia> using StringLiterals

julia> s = f"\N{SECTION SIGN}" #Unicode Entity
"§"

julia> f"\N{SNOWMAN}" #Unicode Entity
"☃"

julia> f"\:mage:" #Emoji Entity 
"\U1f9d9"

julia> f"\<sun>" #LaTeX Entity
"☼"

julia> f"\&euro;" # HTML Entity
"€"
```

Comment: I swear I tried to find a library that do it but I couldn't find it. Thank you very much.